# How to automatically feed a cell value from a range of values, based on its matching condition with other cell value

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

I'm making a time-spending tracker based on the work I do every hour of the day.
Now, suppose I have 28 types of work listed in my tracker (which I also have to increase from time to time), and I have about 8 significance values that I have decided to relate to these 28 types of work, predefined.

I want that, as soon as I enter a type of work in cell 1 - I want the adjacent cell 2 to get automatically populated with a significance value (from a range of 8 values) that is pre-definitely set by me.
Every time I input a new or old occurrence of a type of work, the adjacent cell should automatically get matched with its relevant significance value & automatically get populated in real-time.

I know how to do it using IF, IFS, and IF_OR conditions, but I feel that based on the ever-expanding types of work & significance values, the above formulas will be very big, complicated, and repetitive in the future. I feel there's a more efficient way to achieve it. Also, I don't want it to be selected from a drop-down list.

Guys, please help me out with the most efficient way to handle this. TUIA :)
Also, I've added a snapshot and a sample sheet describing the problem.

[image]

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lHItMo_eesaGnAq1vB5rtS-lgEOFnMHWj7Vh8Xnqqvw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XLOOKUP()` may work. Try-

```
=XLOOKUP(D2,A2:A,B2:B)
```

Or `FILTER()` function like-

```
=FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=D2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula for a whole column:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C14:C,A2:B9,2,0)))
```

Adapt the ranges to your actual tables in order to include in the second argument all the potential values and their significances

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula, that  worked for me (for anybody's reference):
I created another reference sheet, stating the types of work & their significance. From that sheet, I'm using either vlookup, filter, xlookup.Using gforms for inputting my data.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(ROW(D:D)=1,"Significance",A:A="","",TRUE,VLOOKUP(D:D,Reference!$A:$B,2,0)))
```